# How do I test "checkout without a PayPal account" on PayPal sandbox site?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

A customer reported that he couldn't pay for our service using Paypal until he created a Paypal account. Since we have [the necessary setting enabled](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/WAX_landing-outside) that's something that needs debugging.

I'd like to reproduce the problem on https://developer.paypal.com/ but I don't see how to "pay" without either logging into account or creating an account there.

How do I test "checkout without a PayPal account" on Paypal sandbox site?

Comment: What product are you using?  Are you using PayPal Payments Standard or Express Checkout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Payments Standard then this will be cookie based.  If any user on the computer/browser being used has ever signed in to a PayPal account it will assume that you'll be using PayPal and won't give you the guest checkout option.  Clearing your browser cache/cookies should solve this issue, but only until you log in again.

If you want to avoid that you can use Express Checkout with SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole and LANDINGPAGE=Billing.  This will force the Guest Checkout option regardless of any cookies set in the browser.

Comment: I've tried cookies removal a couple of times, it didn't work for me, so I changed the query string - and got to the right thing. Thanks a lot.